# Move constructor for a map

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I think I do understand "the basic IDEA" of move semantics, but now when I'm on the stage of implementing my own map I stopped and started to think about it when I was going to write a use case and walk through for move ctor of map. Correct me if I'm wrong but what I do understand how the whole business of move semantics works is that they suppose to help in avoiding unnecessary copying? Right? Now, take a map for example and just for the purpouse of this example assume that my map is modeled as:

```
class Map
{
Link* impl_;//THIS IS A POINTER TO A LINK WHICH HAS A parent, left and right (of Link type)
Map(Map&& tmp);//move ctor
//unnecessary code ommited
};
```

And here is the snag:
When I'm trying to think of move ctor for my map I cannot see a way of avoiding allocating a new space for all those links which needs to be created and then their pointers swapped with those from a tmp Map object (passed as a arg to my move ctor).
So I do have to allocate space anyway, or don't I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is reassign the Link pointer, since all the other Link pointers are attached to it, they will now be part of the new Map.

```
Map(Map&& tmp) :impl_(tmp.impl_) { tmp.impl_ = nullptr; }
```

This is assuming no other data members.

Comment: yep, I've just copped on while I was finishing writing walk through. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need five operations total: the classic "big three" (copy constructor, copy assignment operator, destructor) and the two new move operations (move constructor, move assignment operator):

```
// destructor
~Map();

// copy constructor
Map(const Map& that);

// move constructor
Map(Map&& that)
{
    impl_ = that.impl_;
    that.impl_ = 0;
}

// copy assignment operator
Map& operator=(const Map& that);

// move assignment operator
Map& operator=(Map&& that)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(impl_, that.impl_);
    return *this;
}
```

The basic idea behind the move assignment operator is that `swap(map1, map2)` has the same observable side effect as `map1 = map2` if you don't inspect `map2` again after performing the swap. [Recall that an rvalue is either a prvalue or an xvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/). By definition, a client *cannot* inspect an object designated by a prvalue twice, because evaluating a prvalue *always* leads to the creation of a new object. The only way to observe this trick is to move from an xvalue such as `std::move(map_variable)`, but then it is *obvious* that `map_variable` is potentially modified.

If you want exception safe assignment even when copying, you can *combine* both the copy assignment operator (taking `const Map&`) and the move assignment operator (taking `Map&&`) to a generalized assignment operator (taking `Map`). Then you only need four operations total:

```
// exception safe copy/move assignment operator
Map& operator=(Map that)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(impl_, that.impl_);
    return *this;
}
```

Note that this variant of the assignment operator takes its argument *by value*. If the argument is an lvalue, the copy constructor initializes `that`, and if the argument is an rvalue, the move constructor does the job. (Also note that specializing `std::swap` is unlikely to result in further significant performance gains if you already provide the move operations.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, one question for I do not understand it clearly, why wouldn't I need copy assignment operator and move assignment operator but only this one? The last one you've described.

Comment: @There: Do you understand when the copy constructor is invoked and when the move constructor? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me/3109981#3109981) for a deeper explanation of this "trick" (it's not really a trick if you understand that parameter passing is just another form of initialization).

Comment: got it. in situation where lvalue is passed then regular copy ctor will do the job and in situation where rvalue is passed move ctor will to it. Correct me if I'm wrong of course.

Comment: @There: As stated by my last paragraph, that's exactly it: "If the argument is an lvalue, the copy constructor initializes `that`, and if the argument is an rvalue, the move constructor does the job."

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the standard disclaimer not to reinvent existing containers, wouldn't it be sufficient to simply assign the root node pointer without doing any allocation?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement move semantics with old C++ (not 0x) but it has to be done explicitly and is more tricky.

```
class X
{
// set access specifiers as required
   struct data
   {
      // all the members go here, just plain easy-to-copy members
   } m;

   data move()
   {
      data copy(m);
      m.reset(); // sets everything back to null state
      return m;
   }

   explicit X( const data& d ) : m(d)
   {
   }
  // other members including constructors
};

X::data func() // creates and returns an X
{
  X x; // construct whatever with what you want in it
  return x.move();
}

int main()
{
   X x(func());
   // do stuff with x
}
```

And X can be made non-copyable and non-assignable in the above, data can have items created on the heap and it is the destructor of X that is responsible for the cleanup. When data is reset by the move() function the parting X will have nothing to clean up because the ownership has been transferred.

Generally the data struct should be public within X but all its members should be private with X a friend. Users therefore do not therefore access anything in there directly.

Note that you are likely to "leak" if you call move() on X without attaching it to another X, thus if you call just func() above you would leak. You should also beware if the constructor of X from data throws (its destructor won't be called so no cleanup will happen automatically). If the copy-constructor of data itself throws you are in even more trouble.
Generally none of these should happen as data contains light stuff (pointers and numbers) and not heavy objects.